# Do tokens ever go to the graveyard and can they be sacrificed or exiled?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I had a card that said something like, "Enchanted creature gets +1/+1 for every creature in your graveyard". Would that also apply to tokens which died in previous turns? Also if I play a card which says, return target creature from the graveyard then can I choose a token?

Right now I use Dice to represent tokens, but not sure what to do once any of my tokens die.

Also for cards which say sacrifice a creature or exile a creature, would these apply to tokens?

Comment: I'm certain whatever card you're referring to would say  …for every creature **card** in your graveyard… Similarly, reanimation spells always say "return target creature **card**" to the battlefield (or your hand). The graveyard never contains creatures, only cards. Tokens are not cards, they are only permanents on the battlefield.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> *If I had a card that said something like, "Enchanted creature gets +1/+1 for every creature in your graveyard".*

There cannot be such a card.

Since "creature" means "creature permanent" which means "creature card or token on the battlefield", and since a card or token cannot be in the graveyard and on the battlefield at the same time, the enchantment would never affect the attached object's power and toughness.

The ability would likely read "Enchanted creature gets +1/+1 for each creature *card* in your graveyard" like [Jarad, Golgari Lich Lord](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJarad%2c%20Golgari%20Lich%20Lord%5d)'s, which means it wouldn't count any tokens since tokens aren't cards.

---

Let's assume there's a card that has the ability "Enchanted creature gets +1/+1 for each creature card and each creature token in your graveyard".

> *Would that also apply to tokens which died in previous turns?*

Tokens go to the graveyard just like a card would. However, they only stay there for a very short period of time. The next time State-Based Actions (SBAs) are performed, they will cease to exist.

Tokens placed in the graveyard on a previous turn will have ceased to exist long ago.

In fact, the effect checking for tokens in the graveyard wouldn't even see the tokens that died this turn except for an extremely short (and practically useless) period of time. The longest scenario might be when the tokens are put into the graveyard during the resolution of a spell or ability, because the SBAs will be only be performed after the spell or ability finishes resolving. It could matter if your opponent has [Hidden Predators](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHidden%20Predators%5d), but that's about it.

---

> *if I play a card which says, return target creature from the graveyard then can I choose a token?*

There cannot be such a card.

Again, creatures (aka creature permanents) cannot be found in the graveyard. It would be impossible to pick a legal target.

The effect would read something like "Return target creature card from your graveyard to the battlefield". This excludes tokens since they aren't cards.

You will never find "Return target creature card or token from your graveyard to the battlefield." for two reasons:

1. Even if there was a token was in the graveyard when targets were chosen, it would have ceased to exists by the time the spell or ability resolved.
2. A rule prohibits the tokens from changing zones once they've left the battlefield.

   > 110.5g A token that has left the battlefield can’t move to another zone or come back onto the battlefield. If such a token would change zones, it remains in its current zone instead. It ceases to exist the next time state-based actions are checked; see rule 704.

---

> *Right now I use Dice to represent tokens,*

It's a poor (and illegal) choice to use a die to represent a type of token since a die can't be tapped.

> *but not sure what to do once any of my tokens die.*

Your tokens would move the graveyard, and soon after they will cease to exist. Most people don't bother physically moving them to the graveyard. Simply adjust the count.

---

> *cards which say sacrifice a creature or exile a creature, would these apply to tokens?*

Yes. "Creature" means "creature permanent" which means "creature card or token on the battlefield".

Comment: Note that there isn't any card that reads "for every creature in your graveyard". That wouldn't make sense, since creatures only exists on the battlefield. Outside of the battlefield, they are creature cards or spells. So it would read "for every creature *card* in your graveyard". And because tokens are not cards, Hidden Predators would never trigger becase of that ability.

Comment: @Pablo, ug, missed that. Fixed

Comment: I use dice for tokens; I think it works just fine. For casual play, at least. When you have a bunch of the same type of token on the battlefield, that's an easy way to deal with it.  It's generally easy enough to track if you tap some of them. Again, for casual, not tournament play.

Comment: I have used dice for tokens as well. I'll use two 10-sided dice. One dice is for tapped, the other for untapped. But it's only for 1 deck and it's still quite annoying, even in casual play. I add a 6-sided if needed to count up to 60.

Comment: @Chris G, Fixed.

Answer (score 11):

Once a creature token "dies", it goes to the graveyard and then ceases to exist. (Some one can came along and quote the Expanded Rules.)

Creature tokens still count as **going** to the graveyard (for the purposes of cards that say "If a creature died..." or "Put a +1/+1 counter on this creature every time a creature dies."), but they are NEVER considered to be **in** the graveyard. Therefore, they won't count for the enchantment you mentioned, they can't be reanimated, etc.

Creature tokens count as creatures in every way; You can sacrifice and exile them to pay costs normally.

Comment: Technically there is a brief moment where they get the +1/+1, but it is too short a window to matter except for weird situations. Added an answer with an example, but yours is correct 99.9% of the time. (I just like weird conditions)

Comment: Tokens aren't exiled when they go to the graveyard; they *cease to exist completely*.  See rule 110.5f: "A token that's phased out, or that's in a zone other than the battlefield, ceases to exist."

Comment: Updated the answer to include the information mentioned by the comments. Thanks guys!

Comment: Re "but they are NEVER considered to be in the graveyard." NOT TRUE. They will be in the graveyard from the time they are placed there until the next time SBAs are performed. Therefore, they WILL count towards the enchantment, if only for a very short will. This can matter for [mtg]Hidden Predators[/mtg]

Answer (score 4):

If you look really hard you can find instances where it matters, but in general you can think of tokens as just ceasing to exist once they leave the battlefield (while triggering just as if they were a card, i.e. activating morbid when going to the graveyard).

So to answer your questions:

- Would that also apply to tokens which died in previous turns? - Nope, they ceased to exist
- Also if I play a card which says, return target creature from the graveyard then can I choose a token? - Nope, they cease to exist before you have the opportunity to do anything
- Right now I use Dice to represent tokens, but not sure what to do once any of my tokens die. - You are fine, just pay attention and see if anything cares about the token going to the graveyard (outside of odd cases like below nothing sees a token in the graveyard). So in your +1/+1 instance you would not get +1/+1.

To go into details, here is comprehensive rule 110.5f.

> 110.5f A token that’s phased out, or that’s in a zone other than the battlefield, ceases to exist. This 
>   is a state-based action; see rule 704. (Note that if a token changes zones, applicable triggered 
>   abilities will trigger before the token ceases to exist.)

There is technically a brief period where the token is in the graveyard (before state-based effects are checked). However no one can do anything during that time.

If you have a weird effect like [Hidden Predators](http://magiccards.info/us/en/263.html) in play the distinction could matter. Also note that while Hidden Predators has an intervening if clause only the if is checked on resolution, not the original trigger condition.

To clarify again however, **there is never a point in time where you can take any action and a token exists in the graveyard**. This is typically simplified to tokens never exist in the graveyard they only enter it, that is close enough for all but the most odd ball cases.

Also it is important to note the other odd rule with tokens, they get stuck once they go somewhere, this happens when something like [Cloudshift](http://magiccards.info/avr/en/12.html) plays tricks without waiting.

> 110.5g A token that has left the battlefield can’t move to another zone or come back onto the 
>   battlefield. If such a token would change zones, it remains in its current zone instead. It ceases 
>   to exist the next time state-based actions are checked; see rule 704.

Comment: another odd-ball corner case involving Tokens ceasing to exist is **Withdraw** and a token copy of **Simian Spirit Guide**. If the first targeted creature is SSG, then the token can be exiled from your hand to pay {1} mana to prevent the second creature from being bounced (all before state-based effects are checked and the token ceases to exist).

Comment: @user1873: No, 110.5g says that the token *can't* be exiled from your hand, so you can't use it to pay {1}.

Comment: @jwodder, they must have updated the rules to take that loophole into account. I do believe that it worked at one point.

Comment: A creature that gets +1/+1 for each creature **card** in the graveyard won't work with tokens, even for a brief moment, because tokens are not **cards**. So it wouldn't even work with something like Hidden Predators.

Comment: Re "To clarify again however, there is never a point in time where you can take any action and a token exists in the graveyard." This is not true. If an effect has two effects, the first of which sends a token to a graveyard, the second will be performed with the token in the graveyard. SBAs are not performed until after the spell or ability finishes resolving.

Comment: Your answer to his question is wrong too. It has nothing to do with the question, and there could actually be tokens in the graveyard in some circumstances. Kudos on mentioning Hidden Predators. I hadn't noticed that you did when I posted mine.

Comment: @ikegami: You are using an odd definition of action that does not match one I have ever seen. I am defining action as something that you get to take such as playing a spell or activating an ability. Of course odd things happen during the resolution of a spell or ability but that is not taking an action, that is resolving a spell or ability.

Comment: @user1873: Since 110.5g causes it to not change zones, you could add infinite mana otherwise (say if it were a replacement effect).

Comment: @Guvante, What you describe is an *effect*. An effect consists of one or more *instructions* that instruct you to perform an *action* such as *destroy*. This is official MTG terminology.

Answer (score -4):

I think tokens can die but they never go to graveyard. they remain on the zone then cease to exist when state-based actions check next time. lets say if 3 tokens die this turn i cannot play ravenous trap for a 0 cost.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it is wrong - to start with, the definition of "dies" is "is put into a graveyard from the battlefield" so your first sentence is contradictory. Please check out some of the other answers here.

Comment: You're right about ravenous trap, but that's because it specifies creature cards and tokens aren't cards, not because the tokens didn't go to the graveyard.